# SQL: Default where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a multi. language website. here is my sample sql

> ```
> select *  from admin_real_estate_category_languages as category_languages
> left join admin_real_estate_categories as category on category_languages.real_estate_category_id = category.id 
> where language = 'jp' and category = 'Area'
> ```

All details have language = 'en' but not all have language = 'jp', if language = 'jp' does not exist in the details I want it to query the language = 'en'.

In short I want the query to have a default where clause if the first where clause does not return anything.

here is a sample of my goal.

> ```
> select *  from admin_real_estate_category_languages as category_languages
> left join admin_real_estate_categories as category on category_languages.real_estate_category_id = category.id 
> where language = 'jp' and category = 'Area' 
> default where language = 'en' and category = 'Area'
> ```

thanks :)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Their SQL syntax can be quite different, you know.

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might not be the best solution since it introduces an additional join, you can solve your problem in this way.

First off, you probably don't want to do select *, that's generally a bad idea. Select the columns that you actually want to use instead (even if that is all columns). If you then have the actual columns you can use COALESCE to solve your problem.

Since you haven't provided the actual schema I'm guessing a bit here, hopefully you'll get the gist of the solution. Also notice that I've switched places on your language table and your category table so I join the language table on the category table, not the other way around as you are doing in the main question.

```
SELECT category.foo, 
       category.bar, 
       category.baz, 
       COALESCE(category_language.text, default_category_language.text)
FROM admin_real_estate_categories AS category 
LEFT JOIN admin_real_estate_category_languages AS category_language 
    ON category_language.real_estate_category_id = category.id 
    AND category_language.language = 'jp'
JOIN admin_real_estate_category_languages AS default_category_language 
    ON default_category_language .real_estate_category_id = category.id
    AND default_category_language.language = 'en'
WHERE category.category = 'Area'
```

Of course, this can quickly escalate and get out of hand if you need too many columns with this type of handling. If you only need this type of handling on one or two columns this strategy usually works fine, but more than that and you really shouldn't use this strategy. In that case I'd probably split the query instead (just make sure not to accidentially create some sort of SELECT N+1 monstrosity if you do that!).

Answer (score 0):

You could select both, order by language and limit to one (to get just the best match).

```
WHERE language in ('jp', 'en') ORDER BY language DESC LIMIT 1
```

This assumes that there is only one translation resource to be returned.

If there are many, you'd have to group by (or just get all and handle it in your application code).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have only one language record you can do this:

```
select *  from admin_real_estate_category_languages as category_languages
left join admin_real_estate_categories as category on category_languages.real_estate_category_id = category.id 
where language IN('jp',' en') and category = 'Area'
```

or in `mysql` this:

```
select *  from admin_real_estate_category_languages as category_languages
left join admin_real_estate_categories as category on category_languages.real_estate_category_id = category.id 
where (language = 'jp' or language =  'en') and category = 'Area'
```